Self-interference of nuclear decay
Consider a stationary atom undergoing radioactive decay. The probability density function for decaying at time $t$ is given by an exponential distribution:
$$p(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$
When decaying, the atom emits a particle; let's assume it is a massive particle. The atom decays at a certain time, and this gives the particle a wavefunction dependent on the time of decay.
The question:
Can the wavefunctions associated with different times of decay interfere with each other?
More details:
The emitted particle has a quantum wavefunction $\phi(x,t)$. However, this wavefunction depends on the time of decay so we should write it as
$$\phi(x,t;t_D)$$
where $t_D$ is the time of decay. In the case of an isolated system, it follows easily that $\phi(x,t;t_D)$ only depends of the position and the time that has elapsed since the decay. So we can write (with $H$ the Heaviside step function):
$$\phi(x,t;t_D)=\psi(x,t-t_D)H(t-t_D)$$
Now consider this system from the perspective of an outside observer, that does not know when the particle has decayed. After some time, the system is in a superposition of all the different $\psi(x,t-t_D)$ for all different decaying times $t_D$ [which form a continuous spectrum].
Interference case One way to combine all those wavefunctions is taking the wheighed integral over $t_D$:
$$\phi_{total}(x,t)=\int_0^{t}p(t_D)\psi(x,t-t_D)dt_D$$
The probability to find a particle at $(x,t)$ is then
$$P(x,t)=\left|\int_0^{t}p(t_D)\psi(x,t-t_D)dt_D\right|^2\label{1}\tag{1}$$
In this integral, the different functions $\psi(x,t-t_D)$ might interfere with each other. For example, if $\psi(x,t-t_A)$ and $\psi(x,t-t_B)$ have opposite complex phase, they could interfere destructively.
No interference case Maybe the different $\psi$s do not interfere at all, because the emitted particle is entangled with the time $|t_D\rangle$ of decay. Then the actual wavefunction would be a tensor product of the position of the particle and the time of decay. It would look like this:
$$\phi_{total}=\int_0^{t}p(t_D)\psi(x,t-t_D)\otimes |t_D\rangle dt_D$$
The probability to find a particle at $(x,t)$ is then:
$$P(x,t)=\int_0^{t}p(t_D)|\psi(x,t-t_D)|^2dt_D\label{2}\tag{2}$$
Conclusion
Which one of my two formulas $\ref{1}$ and $\ref{2}$ is correct? Or is there a third formula that I should use? This boils down to the question: can the $\psi$s from different $t_D$ interfere with each other, and if so: how? I'm also interested if this has been tested experimentally.

Go back to the very beginning. How does your first equation relate to a single nucleus? How is the daughter particle’s wave function dependent on time?

After decay, the daughter particle is governed by the schrodinger equation (at low speed), but that is when you know when the decay has happened

Equation (1) is intended to describe the wavefunction of the daugher particle at time t and location x, from the perspective of an observer that does not know when the nucleus decayed

the wave function is a quantum mechanical solution of the problem, "radioactive decay". This means that there is no individual wave function fitting a single decay as far as our quantum mechanics of today. To test the solution a distribution of decays  is needed, not an individual decays. see this article abou orbitals, not orbits of individual particles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital

I think the issue is much worse than you think. Before the decay, the atom has energy $E_i>E_d$, where the latter is the energy of just the detected particle after the decay. Let $\Delta E=E_i-E_d$ be the energy difference, then because the phase of the initial atom before decay is actually going to be changing, and the phase of the detected particle is also changing, the $\left|\int_0^\tau\psi(t-t_D)e^{-i\Delta t_D}\lambda e^{-\lambda t_D}\mathrm dt_D\right|^2$ will have the interference terms phase cancel out. $\tau$ is the detection time window, that all real detectors have.

@naturallyInconsistent you say that the interference terms cancel out because of phase terms. Does this mean that my equation (2) is correct?

I think that is what we end up working with, yes. Whenever we have no control on the phases, we tend to do this.

In my understanding then, the atom 'measures' when it decays, and therefore the different situations denoted by $t_D$ can not interfere which each other

That is interesting because I thought that only macroscopic objects can perform measurements

This would actually be a variant of the double slit experiment in time, which is very cool: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsVcVW9GI60&ab_channel=DrBenMiles
